# Insert google map in a website with the left locations sidebar

Tags: google-maps, embed

I created a public map into my gmail account. I added to the map different locations. I want to insert the map into my website and I want to show the locations of the places in the left sidebar like in the google maps site, but I can't find how.

This is the map as shown in my site:
[image]

This is what I want to have: (as viewed in the google maps page)
[image]

I embedded the map into my page using the google embed tool
[image]

When entering into "Customize and preview embedded map" there is no option to include the sidebar:
[image]

This is the address of the map:
https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=216330649072490208011.0004daf6e6bfde8dd857d

¿Any suggestion? Thanks for helping

Comment: From where you will load the Markers? google place search??? OR you will drop markers on the map?

Comment: Maybe put google maps in iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do that is like this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fhl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF8%26oe%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D216330649072490208011.0004daf6e6bfde8dd857d

(uses a third party parser [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to parse the KML and render it as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, which are accessible via the sidebar entires)

Comment: Is there any way to have the same example, but without the example buttons (hide,  unhide,  hide markers, etc). So I can put it in my site in an iframe?

Comment: I already tried but I can't make it load the map from the url

Comment: That is probably a different question, which we can't help you with unless you provide your code (preferably) and/or a link to the non-functional page.  There are a lot of pieces that are needed (and a lot of irrelavant stuff in my proof of concept). Do you have a proxy to address the cross-domain restriction on xmlHttpRequest?  Have you included all the required external scripts?

Comment: the link you provided is not working in internet explorer, do you know why?

Comment: See the discussion in your [question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721157/incompatibility-with-geocodezip-map-in-internet-explorer-any-version). In IE8 I am getting a parse error: reason "An invalid character was found in text content. " String, srcText " <description><![CDATA[Sucursales en la rep".  Probably a character encoding issue.