# Incompatibility with geocodezip map in internet explorer (any version)

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, kml, geoxml3

I have this map, as an answer of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16346000/1546946). It uses geocodezip and works well, but it is not working in Internet Explorer. Can you suggest me any solution?

This is the link of the map:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fhl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF8%26oe%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D216330649072490208011.0004daf6e6bfde8dd857d

This is how it looks in other browsers
[image]

This is how it looks in intenet explorer
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: you just need to zoom out. find a way to code the zoom to a fixed position.

Comment: No, it is another issue with IE non-standard behavior.  geoxml3 is getting a syntax error on this line `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');`, at least in some versions...

Comment: if it helps i didn't get that error in ie10, i just zoomed out

Comment: In that case (the message) you should add the following lines to your head of your doc. If you supply the text/html MIME-type, the method should work.

var string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>content</body></html>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<y/>", "text/xml");
return doc.documentElement.localName == "y";

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2011Jul/att-0003/file2.html

Comment: In IE8 I am getting a parse error:
`reason "An invalid character was found in text content.
" String`, `srcText "  <description><![CDATA[Sucursales en la rep" String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a sample code:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You should provide a link showing [where you got the code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial); this is apparently not the first time you’ve done this. Please don’t plagiarize. Also, this doesn’t really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is a difference in the way character encoding is handled in IE, IE is detecting an invalid character in the XML.

[image: Error Message]