# Geocodezip map empty sidebar

Tags: google-maps, kml, geoxml3

I am using the following example of a map in my webpage. ([obtained from an answer in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16346000/1546946)) The source code of both is practically the same, but I can't make the titles of the locations in the sidebar to appear in the page hosted in the client server. (they can be viewed in the original page)

¿Do you know if here is any problem of compatibility or if I can add any extra code to make it work?

This is the example page:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fhl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF8%26oe%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D216330649072490208011.0004daf6e6bfde8dd857d
[image]

This is the page in the client server (I only removed the example buttons, but even with them the information is not showing):
http://www.vitrocar.com.mx/orchard/media/map.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fhl%3Den%26ie%3DUTF8%26oe%3DUTF8%26authuser%3D0%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D216330649072490208011.0004daf6e6bfde8dd857d
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a proxy on my server:

http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp

Defeats the purpose and will not work.  You need to have the proxy on your server.

The proxy is used to overcome the [cross-domain restriction on XmlHttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+proxy+cross-domain+restriction) (XmlHttpRequest is used by geoxml3 to access the remote KML, it can only access XML in the same domain as the website).